# How to make SELinux permissive on a Knox Samsung device?

Tags: root-access, selinux, samsung-knox

I have a Samsung note 2014 which I rooted following [this tutorial](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/root-samsung-galaxy-note-10-1-2014-lte-p605-cf-auto-root-tool/). However I now have problems with SELinux which (apparently) is preventing me from installing a Linux virtual box. I backed up and uninstalled KNOX using Titanium backup but still no success. When I type `setenforce permissive` in a terminal, if get no error message but when I type `getenforce`, I get "enforcing".

Is there any way I can change this? The device is running Android 4.3.

Comment: Have you 0x1 Knox flag? Have you installed any ROMs in the meantime? You have uninstalled the KNOX APP, but that doesn't have an effect on this. Have you flashed a custom Kernel with SEPermissive set on it? You could try the app recommended here: http://techbeasts.com/2014/02/25/how-to-disable-selinux-on-a-rooted-android-device/  but I'm doubtful to be honest.

Comment: I think I have the 0x1 flah because I can't get new updates. And not I've not flashed any ROMs. Should I go for Cyanogenmod?

Comment: Up to you what ROM to use, but I would not recommend CyanogenMod outside of a STABLE release, there are numerous known bugs in nightlies! It's all preference, try a few and see what you like. Don't forget BACKUPS! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a local terminal shell, by using a "Terminal Emulator" like app. Otherwise you will not get an `su`'able shell. Since AOS 4.2.2, ADB is not letting you use "su", to get root shell, on stock "Enforced" SELinux devices.

Then do this:

```
su 0 setenforce 0
```

If you need to make this permanent to last between re-boots, you need to find where this is originally set in the various `init.*.rc` files in boot.img and change it, and reflash...

**EDIT: 2015-09-22**

The above trick **no longer work** on Stock devices using AOS 4.4.4 and above, even with insecure kernels. (Such as those provided by *cf-autoroot*.) That you can blame Google who made *Enforcing* permanent. Your only option, other than re-compiling your own ROM, is learning about *SEAndroid* and context changing using SuperSU's `supolicy` command to inject the policy files.

Comment: The commands didn't work: I ran 'getenforce' immediately after and the result was "Enforcing". But maybe modifying the files in boot.img would work. How should I flash it? Using Odin of course but how exactly. (Usually the costom ROM is given already.)

Comment: @Reza: Try again by updating your SuperSU (currently 1.99r2). I think older SuperSU < 1.94 are not behaving well with recent SELinux's.

Comment: I have Supersu v1.94 and it's the same version on the Play Store. Where can I get 1.99?

Comment: From [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053).

Comment: Doesn't work for me (SuperSU 2.01)

Answer (score 1):

### **Getting around Militant SELINUX**

You need to run a custom kernel build.

1. Samsung open source is [here](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception.do)
2. My harvested info for setting up your build system for Linux is [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=59718268&postcount=3)
3. The kernel patch you will need to fix SElinux to permissive is [here](https://github.com/moonbutt74/kernel_samsung_SM-T530_EUR_LL/commit/2e4de065b266a7a15e1d392ff3f80f5c089a423d). It should absolutely work for Kitkat source as well.

I would post the diff but it doesn't wrap right.

You should not need to set the SElinux boot flag and userspace disable options during `menuconfig`, but do remember to disable Samsung anti-root in the kernel hacking section.

Comment: The 3 step, it's link is dead, it leads to a 404 error on github, can you please either elaborate on what it was doing or post a new link.

Comment: You should have posted the diff. Link is dead as mentioned by @Matt07211.

Comment: @Marc.2377 if my memory servers me correctly    (figured out how to myself at a latter point) it was a simple 1 line/1 value change in the selinux subdir/makefile. I'll see if I can locate it again

Comment: Found it, basically you set this to false I believe, it's Been a long time and I was a utterly clueless back then https://github.com/Matt07211/android_kernel_samsung_xcover3lte/blob/b920c232fd2d8246a66b4e2a0c8c5e536850025a/security/selinux/Makefile#L7

Comment: Thanks @Matt07211.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal emulator app, enter `su` and then enter `setenforce 0`. Now check the phone. It should show  "permissive" until a reboot. You can execute the commands again after reboot or get [SELinuxModeChanger](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2524485) from XDA which switches it automatically at boot.

Comment: Which app from XDA specifically?

Comment: It is called SELinuxModeChanger.