# SELinux temporary set to permissive

Tags: rooting, selinux, magisk, samsung-knox, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I am using a Galaxy s10+, rooted with magisk, no custom ROM, no custom kernel and no custom recovery. The rooting is heavily limited because of the SELinux enforce mode. Actually, no root command in termux works because of SELinux. I do not want to disable SELinux permanently for security reasons. What I want is something similar to the command "setenforce 0". This does not work on my phone however, and I think it could be KNOX related. It gives no errors but the output of "getenforce" is still enforced.

Is there a way to set SELinux to permissive mode only temporarily until next reboot on rooted Samsung galaxy s10+ with magisk, everything stock?

The linked duplicate is what i already tried, and it also says it does not work after 2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make SELinux permissive on a Knox Samsung device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64643/how-to-make-selinux-permissive-on-a-knox-samsung-device)

Comment: That is what i already tried as I said. The answer says that it no longer works after 2015.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526

Comment: ... and the answer remains the same after 2015: you need to run a custom kernel

Comment: @alecxs and OP insists on not having a custom kernel in 4 questions asked previously: [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214733/218526), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214594/218526), [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214598/218526), [4](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214601/218526).

Comment: @Selinuxguy just built the kernel without `SECURITY_SELINUX_ENFORCING=y`. May be the source code needs to be patched.

Comment: `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y`

Comment: @alecxs yes, with that kernel starts in permissive mode, later enforced by init.

Answer (score -1):

I almost literally did the same thing.. I went after an LG K30 Premier Pro and comes down to SElinux. I did mine to prove you can "Root" a phone without deactivating the bootloader. Still having hard time cause without deactive it either says your not rooted or it does say it and the phone inner programs send you an email and tell you they are going into hidding inside a FireStick
. pretry. Funny really. ..
Ok herwnis the email com.lge.software.cliptray
Version: null (0)
SD Maid

Version: 4.14.27 (41427)
Device

Fingerprint: lge/cv3_lao_com/cv3:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.026/19155140321d4:user/release-keys